# How to preserve doublequotes + prevent weird numbers in YAML output

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

My app is loading and analyzing a nested YAML file, extracting each single Key/Value pair with the RepresentationModel. Some **Values** will be changed, then I write back the YAML file. Input file is:

```
account: 
  menu: 
    dev: "Device Settings" # Item comment 1
    port: "Portal Accounts"
    prof: "Personal Information"
  ports: 
# Comment line
    desc: "Below is a list of available portals. You can use the sections below to manage each portal account."
    det: "Manage Accounts"
    no_enabled: "No portals are currently enabled."
    ti: "Account Access"
  pro: 
    ti: Information
```

but the output file looks like

```
account:
  menu:
    dev: Device Settings changed
    port: Portal Accounts changed
    prof: Personal Information changed
  ports:
    desc: Below is a list of available portals. You can use the sections below to manage each portal account. changed
    det: Manage Accounts changed
    no_enabled: No portals are currently enabled.
    &1735269872 ti: Account Access
  pro:
    ti: Information
```

- How to preserve the doublequotes from the input file when using Yaml.Save()?
- What is this weird number &1735269872 and how to prevent that it is written when saving the YAML? In longer files other numbers appear in different places.
- Is it possible to preserve the comments and maybe even better to access them while browsing the YAML?

Answer (score 0):

That "weird" number is a standard YAML [anchor](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2785586), which is normally only necessary for recursive data references. The only thing weird about it is why your C# YAML library inserts it in here, as there is no corresponding alias pointing to it. It might be that it is confused because of the key `ti` occurring later on in the file, but without an actual node alias to refer to the anchor that `&1735269872` is completely superfluous.

The YAML specification explicitly states that

> Comments are a presentation detail and must not be used to convey content information

All libraries that I know off, apart from my `ruamel.yaml` (for Python),  discard comments within the file which is the more easy thing to do (some keep the comment if it occurs at the beginning of the file.

But even that ruamel.yaml when used to roundtrip your input YAML doesn't preserve the **unnecessary** quotes around the value scalars in your input and standardizes the output of strings. yamldotnet  supports  setting scalar properties to be specified through the YamlMember attribute since version 3.6.0, but I cannot find examples of how that is done. However using that would most likely also affect your scalar keys. Your **inconsistent use of quotes** around scalars would require preservation of quoting knowledge on an individual string basis.

Maybe you should ask yourself what you lose in clarity by this inconsistency and accept non-quoted string scalars everywhere on not just in some places in our input.

`ruamel.yaml` might help you if you can call its Python functionality from your C# program, but I never tried that direction myself (only the other way around).

Comment: Thank you for your very useful comments. I think this will help to explain app users that complain about the different output YAML file format that the file is still according to the YAML standard. But the anchor is still weird and shouldn't appear.

Comment: I completely agree the that the anchor is weird. I tried to look at the source, but although the structure of the yamldotnet and my ruamel.yaml is similar, my C# fluency is not big enough to understand where (let alone why) the emitter decides to insert the anchor. Maybe the yamldotnet author can shed more light, he is here on [so] regularily, but has not been the last week and a half.